# How to include file pcap.h in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In the [Apple doc for pcap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pcap.3.html) they have used

```
#include <pcap.h>
```

but `#include <pcap.h>`  in my project gives error that "file not found".

Is there any library need to be imported to include pcap.h in my project?  However apple man page has not mentioned it. Question is, how do I include pcap.h in my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library `libpcap` is not available on the iPhone OS platform, but is only available on the Mac OS X platform.

Short answer, you can't use this library as-is on the iPhone, but you may be able to port some of the functionality to the iPhone. You will not be able to perform packet capture on the iPhone because of security restrictions unless the system is jailbroken.

Comment: Petesh,thanks for reply.Actually there is an app on appstore named "Netstat" I'm trying to have such functionality in my app. Any idea how do they do that?  -https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8

Comment: I think it may use an extremely cut-down version of the netstat source from the opendarwin project (but I could be way off base on this, but it is the thing that makes the most sense to me)

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the iPhone app -NetStat- you were mentioning. As I understood it opens up listeners for all ports.

You could use a socket helper class and setup listeners for necessary ports.

Here is an example http://code.google.com/p/entropydb/wiki/SocketWrapper